# Gap Statistics with Standard 1 error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, k-means, montecarlo

I have implemented a Kmeans using Scikit Learn command and I have tried Elbow and Silhoutte Coefficient to find the optimal K. I am planning to use gap statistics to further verify my results.

```
def optimalK(data, nrefs=3, maxClusters=15):


gaps = np.zeros((len(range(1, maxClusters)),))
resultsdf = pd.DataFrame({'clusterCount':[], 'gap':[]})
for gap_index, k in enumerate(range(1, maxClusters)):

    # Holder for reference dispersion results
    refDisps = np.zeros(nrefs)

    for i in range(nrefs):

        # Create new random reference set
        randomReference = np.random.random_sample(size=data.shape)

        # Fit to it
        km = KMeans(k)
        km.fit(randomReference)

        refDisp = km.inertia_
        refDisps[i] = refDisp

    km = KMeans(k)
    km.fit(data)

    origDisp = km.inertia_

    # Calculate gap statistic
    gap = np.log(np.mean(refDisps)) - np.log(origDisp)

    # Assign this loop's gap statistic to gaps
    gaps[gap_index] = gap

    resultsdf = resultsdf.append({'clusterCount':k, 'gap':gap}, ignore_index=True)

return (gaps.argmax() + 1, resultsdf)
```

However my plots for gap statistic is increasing therefore optimal number of clusters is always the end point for my range of clusters. Assume I am defining cluster range to be from 1 to 10 then optimal will be 10.

According to the internet websites and the original paper the workaround is to implement the standard 1 error in which

GAP(K)> GAP(K+1)- S(K+1)

Can anyone explain to me how to implement this in the above code? I do not know how to calculate the S(k+1) since it involves finding the standard deviation of the reference distribution.

```
s(k+1) = sd(k+1)*square_root(1+(1/B))
```

B is the number of copies of Monte Carlo Samples. I look at different websites but it seems they did not implement the gap statistics with standard 1 error.

Answer (score 2):

```
def gap_stat(data,label):
    k = len(np.unique(label))
    n = data.shape[0]
    p = data.shape[1]
    D_r = []
    C_r = []
    for label_number in range(0,k):
        this_label_index = np.where(label==label_number)[0]
        temp_sum = 0
        pairwise_distance_matrix = 
    euclidean_distances(data[this_label_index],squared=True)
        D_r.append(np.sum(pairwise_distance_matrix))
        C_r.append(float(len(this_label_index)))

    W_r = np.sum(np.asarray(D_r)/(2*np.asarray(C_r)))
    gap_stats = np.log(float(p*n)/12)-(2/float(p))*np.log(k)- 
    np.log(W_r)
    return(gap_stats)
```

Comment: You need to load package to calculate pairwise distance by: from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

Comment: What is label in your code? what does it represent?

Comment: I will be appreciate if you can explain this ? since there is no label in gab statistics, it is unsupervised learning methods to find the number of clusters

Comment: How is this even implementing that standard 1 error method described in the question?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: I write the code according to the article: https://statweb.stanford.edu/~gwalther/gap

Comment: I think your goal is to find the best cluster number, so, you can try different k by using k-means, then you can get label from k-means, label is a list of which cluster each point belongs to